# in-App purchase restore button alternative placement

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

My app was rejected because of not having 'restore' button... i'm in a situation where i don't have space to put 'restore' button, i have tableView and on the right navigation, i have segment and left is obviously 'back' button.. the only option left for me is to drag down the tableview, which will messup my beautiful interface...

current purchase process: user taps on the tableview, it brings up an Alert to confirm user wants to buy product, upon confirmation, in-App purchase methods fires... i was wondering if there is an alternate way to put 'restore' button or should i put 'restore' button in alert or actionsheet maybe? and not getting rejected by Apple again? please help!

Comment: you can offer to the user the restore option in a popup window or in an alert view. the safe way to show this option on the same screen where the products are... or if you want to just show an auto-popup when the app starts, that could be a nice solution as well... or we developed an application which automatically tries to restore everything in the background, there was not issue with it, Apple approved that solution as well, and in that particular case we didn't put any "Restore" button in the app.

Comment: @holex thanks, can you share some code if possible? I'm pretty new and its my first app... how would i keep track of users who purchased the app before so that i can 'activate' restore in the background only for the users who have already purchased the app?

Comment: I'm not sure the code is the point here, I think the logic is much more important. we put the restore procedure in the `–application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, and it runs in a background thread, so it does not delay the regular launch, it runs every time when the app starts with the users's current AppStore account. I cannot say it is a regular solution for the problem, but it worked for that app.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a settings page in your app anywhere?  Most apps with IAP put the "Restore purchases" there.  If your app is a list of items the user can purchase, consider adding a final row in your table view and have that row be "restore purchases"

Comment: @Ahmad So your app is a table view with one item in it?

Comment: No, there are list of cells in the tableview, what i meant to say was that i only have one product/item to sell in in-App purchase.

Comment: @Ahmad Would it work to make the alert that comes up have 3 buttons (cancel, restore, buy)?

Comment: that's what i was thinking but i'm not sure if Apple would be fine with this? i went through the documentation but didn't find anything related to this. how can i confirm this?